# Fixing detached branches in Git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I've used [the script](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info) provided by GitHub to change author info of a GIT repository. While running the script there were some errors which resulted in each branch being duplicated as the origin. I need to keep the origin branches and delete the others. I can't switch to the origin branches because it throws an error:

```
fatal: A branch named 'Development' already exists.
```

How can I restore my repository to only keep the origin branches?
My branches look like this in sourcetree:

[image: sourcetree]

Comment: Delete the local ‘Development’ branch with `git branch -D Development` and then you should be able to checkout origin/Development.

Comment: The script to change authors / committers *does* duplicate the commits (and hence the branches). That's *how* it changes things. You can't actually *change* any commit; you have to make a new, different, new-and-improved commit. This affects every subsequent commit. What you end up with is typically, effectively, a new, incompatible repository; that seems to be the case here, for instance.

Comment: This happened to me when I did 'git checkout <branch>' in which <branch> was not a local branch. Even though I didn't use the -b option it seemed to go ahead and create a duff branch anyway. Then when I tried to actually track the remote branch with ' git checkout --track <branch>' it complained that the branch already existed. I was able to delete it using the command that Cristian above gave and then re-checkit out correctly. I wish gitlab didn't do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reset your `Development` branch to the origin one:

```
git checkout Development
git reset --hard origin/Development
```

That should be enough.